# mysql checking permission takes a long time

Tags: mysql

I have a table(innodb) with about 50 million rows, tries to drop it, then it hangs, I checked process list:

checking permission

what is checking permissions state and why does drop table needs it?

Comment: Similar situation, it takes 13 minutes to check permissions on DROP.
It's a bug, whatever it is doing it has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: @John I can confirm: I have exactly 34 rows in my mysql.user table, and a DROP TABLE has been running for the last 12 minutes. It completed while I was writing this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html, the state "Checking Permissions" is defined as follows:

•checking permissions
The thread is checking whether the server has the required privileges to execute the statement.

I found something concerning Slow Checking Permissions in forums.mysql.com
[The thread of responses in this forum entry](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,274892,274892) suggests reducing the number of user entries in mysql.user.

IMHO, the "Checking Permissions" issues is a hard one to fathom even for experts.